# Parsing fifo output for unique lines only

Tags: python, fifo

New to python.

I'm trying parse the output of a strange fifo and having trouble figuring it out. Basically i have:

```
fifoopen = open("./foo/fifoA")
while True:
    line = fifoopen.readline()
print line
```

Which works fine and prints the output of the fifo as it is fed in by the application on the other end. However, that application randomly sends duplicate or triplicate lines to the fifo. So I am looking for advice on how to parse the output of the fifo to print new, unique lines only.

I appreciate any help you might give,

-Don

Answer (score 1):

Are you only interested in eliminating *consecutive* duplicates? Or *any* duplicates? If any duplicates, I would suggest keeping a set of previously-seen lines; otherwise, keeping a copy of the last line seen would be sufficient. In either case, if (new line) == (old line(s)), skip it.

Answer (score 1):

The [itertools documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes) has a recipe for just this:

```
def unique_justseen(iterable, key=None):
    "List unique elements, preserving order. Remember only the element just seen."
    # unique_justseen('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') --> A B C D A B
    # unique_justseen('ABBCcAD', str.lower) --> A B C A D
    return imap(next, imap(itemgetter(1), groupby(iterable, key)))
```

Although it might be more readable as a generator expression:

```
def unique_justseen(iterable, key=None):
    return (next(i[0]) for i in groupby(iterable, key))
```

You can use this like so:

```
for line in unique_justseen(fifoopen):
   print line
```